# Extracting and altering base64 image data in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I want to alter the image data of a base64 image.
Altering is in this case encrypting the image data but it can be replace by toUpperCase() for simplicity's sake.
I get the image data with this code snippet :

```js
let originalImage = myBase64Image
let imageData = originalImage.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
imageData = imageData.toUpperCase()
```

Altering the imageData does not result in the changing of the original image data.
I was wondering if there way to bring imageData back to a full base64 image that I can use in an html element for example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ToUpper() of Base64 data would not be reversible, as Base64 uses both, lower and uppercase letters, which have different values. Once you changed everything to uppercase, you can't decide which letters would have to be reverted to lowercase.

Comment: That is not important as I only use it to replace an encryption algorithm that would make things far more difficult to explain. The point is that I want to alter the data of a base64 image and convert it back to a base64 image. I should have mentionted it more clearly.

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet (ie including a base64 image) to illustrate the difficulty?

Comment: Hey Haworth good remark. Unfortunately I can't as any base64 image exceeds the data limit of a snippet on stack overflow (I tried like 5 times). If you go to this link you can you can select any file that is then converted to a base64 image https://www.base64-.image.de/. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.